# MVVM Binding Views to TabControlItems - Views don't display

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, tabcontrol

I want to display different views in `TabControlItems` in my MainView.

To do this I've created a class like this :

```
public sealed class TabItem
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public ViewModelBase Content { get; set; }
}
```

That I call in a `List`in my ViewModel :

```
private ObservableCollection<TabItem> _views;
public ObservableCollection<TabItem> Views
{
    get { return _views; }
    set
    {
        _views = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => Views);
    }
}

public IndexMainViewModel()
{
    Views = new ObservableCollection<TabItem>();
    Views.Add(new TabItem { Header = "Export", Content = new ExportViewModel() });
    Views.Add(new TabItem { Header = "Import", Content = new ImportViewModel() });  
}
```

**EDIT** And then display in my View :

```
<window xmlns:views="clr-namespace:EDICOT_Module_Import_Export_Articles.View"
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:EDICOT_Module_Import_Export_Articles.ViewModel"
xmlns:model="clr-namespace:EDICOT_Module_Import_Export_Articles.Model.Classes"
DataContext="{Binding IndexMainVM, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

   <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Views}">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:TabItem}">
            <DataTemplate.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ImportViewModel}">
                    <views:ImportView />
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ExportViewModel}">
                    <views:ExportView />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataTemplate.Resources>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Content}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.Resources>

    <TabControl.ItemTemplate >
        <DataTemplate >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

The problem is that it displays only the header but not the content (the view), it shows instead the path to the TabItem class.

To give more infos : I've truncated the code to keep only what the topic needs and I use MVVM Light.

I really don't get what I miss here ! Thx for your help.

Comment: Edited code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that each tab is bound to an instance of `TabItem`.  You have DataTemplates for `vm:ExportViewModel` and `vm:ImportViewModel`.  Do you see your error now?

There are many solutions for this.  Simplest is to move the Header text into the base view model and bind that Tab control to a collection of ViewModels.

Another alternative would be to add a DataTemplate for `TabItem`, stick a ContentControl in it, and bind *that* to the view model.  Here's some xaml-like pseudocode to illustrate this idea:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:TabItem}">
    <ContentControl Content={Binding Content}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

You may have to move the templates for your view models into the resources of the ContentControl, but I don't think that's necessary.  You might need to tweak the TabItem data template so that it fills the tab window as well.

A ***third*** option would be to implement a custom [DataTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and use *that* in your Tab control.  In this selector, simply crack open your TabItem and look at the Content property for the type.  You can browse the source code for the default DataTemplateSelector to find out how to get the correct template for the given type.  This method gets your hands deep in the gore of WPF, which is an interesting trip.  <strike>I've done it once, and I prefer to not do it again.</strike> <strike>Actually, for your needs, the trip won't be as bad as mine.</strike> The default selector doesn't do squat, so returning `base.SelectTemplate` is worthless.  I dug around in the framework for an example of how it should be implemented.

```
public class TabItemDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate
        SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var viewModel = item as TabItem;
        if (item == null)
            return null;
        else
            item = viewModel.Content;

        FrameworkElement fe = null;
        if (container is ContentPresenter)
            fe = (container as ContentPresenter)
                    .TemplatedParent as FrameworkElement;
        else
            fe = container as FrameworkElement;

        var key = new DataTemplateKey(item.GetType());
        return fe.TryFindResource(key) as DataTemplate;
    }
}
```

add an instance of that to a Resource somewhere

```
<derp:TabItemDataTemplateSelector x:Key="tidts"/>
```

then bind that to [ContentTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol.contenttemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Views}"
            ContentTemplateSelector={StaticResource tidts}>
```

Comment: thx a lot for your answer, I guessed a thing like that on instanciatiating `TabItems` but it stills a bit gloomy at the momentn can you precise a bit ? I'll look closer to your first and second solution and I'll edit if it works. For the third solution, do you have some more explanation or samples ? - Thx mate

Comment: @RizzCandy The default DataTemplateSelector looks at the type of object in the binding, then looks up the visual tree for a DataTemplate whose DataType property matches this type.  It knows nothing about your TabItem or its Content property.  Added some c# and xaml like pseudocode which should guide you.

Comment: Thx a lot, but I tried many of the solutions without success and went to that conclusion : as I'm using MVVM Light, my TabItem property `ViewModelBase` is undefined even when I had the ViewModel in my TabItem collection. So when the Content is called in the view, it doesn't know what to display. For the moment I don't know how to figure that out !

Comment: You were right I was just missing the syntax of the `DataTemplate.Ressources` and the `ContentControl`. Works perfectly. I've edited my code to put on the right syntax. I'll keep your third solution as an asset for another case cause it looks very interesting.

Comment: I happen to find myself back on the data template selector chain gang, and my example implementation absolutely does not work, as far as I can tell.  The base implementation of DataTemplateSelector does jack shit.  Now I gotta dig through everything and find what I did before :(